# What is the absolute maximum of $y = x^2$ on the interval $(-2, 2]$?

Tags: calculus

What is the absolute maximum of $y = x^2$ on the interval $(-2, 2]$?

My assumption was that the absolute max would be $4$ and it would occur at $x = 2$. However, according to an example I found, there is no absolute max since the interval is open on one end and that end would have the same value if it was closed.

How about on the interval $(-1, 2)$ - I would think that in this case the absolute max would be $4$ at $x = 2$.

I understand the extreme value theorem requires a closed interval, but is it possible to have absolute extrema exist at endpoints that are closed on only one side?

Comment: You are correct about the absolute maximum of $y = x^2$ in the interval $(-2, 2]$.  Could you share the example you found that led you to doubt that answer?  In the interval $(-1, 2)$, $y = x^2$ has no absolute maximum since $2$ is not in the interval.

Comment: At $x = 2$, you have $x^2 = 4$. There is no other $x\in(-2, 2]$, such that $x^2 > 4$, thus $4$ is indeed the maximum.

Comment: It is of course $4$, attained at a single point, $2$. There's no need for major theorems. On any $(a,b)$ this function has no maximum, but on $[a,b)$ or $(b,a]$, with $|a|\geq |b|$, this function has a maximum $a^2$ at a unique point, $a$.

Comment: The original example is a graphical one and there doesn't appear to be a way for me to upload a screenshot. However, the concept is identical. Thanks